# scss not compiled from app directory Angular 6+

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular2-template

Hello I just created test angular app with command `ng new my-sassy-app --style=scss` project created successfully, but `scss` files doesn't compiled from app directory for example: when I write `body {background: red}` in `app.component.scss` but when I write same code in `src/style.scss` `scss` compiled well.
I don't know what is problem.

**Not working screenshot**

[image: Not working]

**Working screenshot when I type same in** `src/style.scss`

[image: Working]

Comment: Did you added this app.component.scss in app.component.ts styles array?

Comment: Yes of course it was added by default

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have that line at your angular.json. Take care for style:"**scss**"

```
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  },
```

Comment: your version is old, now `"style":"scss"` is `"styleext":"scss"`